# Derivative of dot product?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

What's the derivative ${\partial \over \partial x} \langle x, f(x)\rangle$?

According to the product rule it should be $1\cdot f(x) + x \cdot f'(x) $ but in [my previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361637/having-trouble-checking-that-this-surface-is-regular) I was told that this makes no sense.

Here $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ and $1$ is the constant one vector and $x \in \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: The link is down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $f,g: I\subset \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^n$ be smooth maps, and $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ be the usual dot product in $\Bbb R^n$. So: $$\begin{align}\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\langle f(x),g(x)\rangle &= \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)g_i(x) \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}(f_i(x)g_i(x)) \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n(f'_i(x)g_i(x)+f_i(x)g'_i(x)) \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^nf'_i(x)g_i(x)+\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(x)g'_i(x)\\ &= \langle f'(x),g(x)\rangle + \langle f(x),g'(x)\rangle.\end{align}$$

Comment: Did you mean $$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\langle {x},f(x)\rangle = 2 \langle {\bf 1},f'(x)\rangle.  $$?

Comment: $$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\langle {\bf 1},f(x)\rangle = \langle {\bf 1}',f(x)\rangle + \langle {\bf 1},f'(x)\rangle = \langle {\bf 1},f'(x)\rangle.$$