# Derivative of dot product with transposed function

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

According to this post [Derivative of dot product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362611/derivative-of-dot-product) I have a similar task:

> $$\langle f(x),g(x) \rangle = f(x)g(x)^T=j(x)$$
>   I have to show: $j'(x)=g'(x)f(x)^T+g(x)^Tf'(x)$

I know how to differentiate the dot product, but I have trouble with this transposed function. My results:
$$(\langle f(x), g(x) \rangle)'= \left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^m f_n(x)g_n(x)\right)=...=\langle f'(x),g(x)\rangle + \langle f(x),g'(x)\rangle=j'(x)$$

I'm not sure about the last step that $\langle f(x), g'(x) \rangle = f(x)^T g'(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the dot product commutes, so $$f(x)g'(x)^T= \langle f(x), g'(x)\rangle = \langle g'(x), f(x)\rangle =f(x)^Tg'(x) $$